# Verilog: Multiply signed by unsigned

Tags: verilog, modelsim

Right now I'm trying to adjust the amplitude of 12 bit signed input by an 8-bit variable.

```
module mixer_4input (in, amp, out);

input signed    [11:0]  in;
input           [7:0]   amp;
wire signed     [8:0]   signed_amp;
output signed  [19:0]   out;
  
assign signed_amp = amp; 
assign out = $signed((in  >> 8) * signed_amp);  
//assign out = $signed(amp) * (in >> 8); //this one works wrong too
  
endmodule
```

[modelsim screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqMZ.png)

But the output is either have a missing sign or just completely wrong.
radix type in modelsim is set according to what I wait to see

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will not sign-extend as I think you are expecting:

```
assign signed_amp = amp;
```

`amp` is 8-bits wide and unsigned. Verilog will widen it to 9 bits by adding a `1'b0` to the left, whatever the state of bit 7 of `amp`. The fact that `signed_amp` is signed is irrelevant.

To make this work, you need to first convert `amp` to be signed using the `$signed` system function:

```
assign signed_amp = $signed(amp);
```

I think this is also not behaving as you expect:

```
assign out = $signed(amp) * (in >> 8);
```

`>>` is a *logical* shift right. Because of that, zeros will be added on the left. I suspect you need this:

```
assign out = $signed(amp) * (in >>> 8);
```

using the *arithmetic* shift right operator - `>>>`, which will preserve the sign of `in`.

Comment: I used >> 8  to divide input by 256 so then i can multiply by 0...255. 
It turned out that "12 bit signed" portion of variable is stored in first 12 bits (duh!), while modelsim shows value of whole 19 bits, which is misleading